# I can't mute an AudioContext

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying for the first time to use Web Audio API in Javascript.

For a personal project i'm trying to control the volume, but I have some difficulties.

I'm using this git project : https://github.com/kelvinau/circular-audio-wave

In this project I added this function that use in the function play() :

```
changeVolume() {
    const volume = this.context.createGain();
    volume.gain.value = 0.1;
    volume.connect(this.context.destination)
    this.sourceNode.connect(volume)
}
```

When I set the gain to 0 it doesn't mute the sound. But when i set to 3 its working and the sound is louder.

Do you know why I can increase the volume but I can't lower it ?

Comment: Can you create some example code that reproduces your problem?  And even better, post a JSFiddle link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are describing it sounds as if there is still a direct connection from the `sourceNode` to the `destination` of the `context`.

It should work if you remove [this line](https://github.com/kelvinau/circular-audio-wave/blob/master/src/js/circular-audio-wave.js#L324) from the original example.

```
this.sourceNode.connect(this.context.destination);
```